# Spinning Pinwheel of death on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am a developer working on an in house application.  I have gotten several complaints about getting the [Spinning pinwheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinning_pinwheel) in the iOS application I maintain.  Can anyone tell me if this is actually something that can happen on iOS (**not OS X**.  **I know this is common on the desktop OS when an application becomes unresponsive to input.**) I have done a great deal of searching on Google and am coming up empty handed.  I'm beginning to wonder about the accuracy of this bug report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that there is any spinning pinwheels in iOS. What your users are likely reporting is a UIActivityView spinning round and round and don't understand the difference between the two (you know how some users are...).

Comment: I agree, and the ActivityView is only used when using the network, or when the developer chooses to display it. It is not used when the app is hanging.

Comment: @RedEagle2000 I'll mark this as the answer tonight if there are not other responses.  The main user who reported it is fairly technically savvy, and I showed him a picture of the pinwheel to be sure we were talking about the same thing.  I still think there is a chance he was incorrect, but I want to be absolutely sure.